# How to transpose column without SQL procedures

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, pivot

I have a SQL table which saves values like the below picture

[image: Original table]

Now I need to transpose this table like the one shown below.

[image: Transposed table]

I need to do this without using Stored procedure. I am trying to bind the 2nd table to 4 datagridview checkbox column.

Comment: you can start studying about `PIVOT`; try some code and come back here

Comment: "I need to do this without using SQL" - how exactly do you expect to do it?

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to do this without writing a new stored proc or any temporary tables,cursor,etc. Edited my question now. I am learning pivot in SQL now. But this one seems to be difficult to do even with pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

This should work however you may need to try and make it dynamic if your values in C2 are not always going to be `[MP], [KL], [OL], [IFL]` Also be careful using `CROSS JOIN` if your data sets are relatively large:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp(C1 INT
              , C2 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
      (1
     , 'MP'),
      (2
     , 'KL'),
      (3
     , 'OL'),
      (3
     , 'IFL');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      C1
    , [MP] = CASE
               WHEN [MP] = C1 THEN 'TRUE'
               ELSE ''
            END
    , [KL] = CASE
               WHEN [KL] = C1 THEN 'TRUE'
               ELSE ''
            END
    , [OL] = CASE
               WHEN [OL] = C1 THEN 'TRUE'
               ELSE ''
            END
    , [IFL] = CASE
                WHEN [IFL] = C1 THEN 'TRUE'
                ELSE ''
            END
FROM   #temp AS A
      CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT [MP]
                   , [KL]
                   , [OL]
                   , [IFL]
               FROM
                    (SELECT C1
                         , C2
                     FROM   #temp) AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX(C1) FOR C2 IN([MP]
                                                              , [KL]
                                                              , [OL]
                                                              , [IFL])) AS PivotTable) AS B;
```

RESULT:

[image]